# regex special char?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a character that does the same thing as the asterix mark in unix (*).. that is, ignore everything after that letter ? (Including special characters)
For example, i want to match the following with just one regex expression

```
http://example.com/blah
http://example.com/blah/blah
http://example.com/blah?blah/blah
```

Sorry, couldn't find this somewhere but i have a feeling it must be something elementary.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.*` (a dot followed by a star). Dot means "match ([almost](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)) any character". Star means "zero or more times". It does not *ignore* anything, it *matches* anything. You could try this regular expression:

`^http://abc\.com/blah.*$`

Or perhaps just this (depending on how you are using it):

`^http://abc\.com/blah`

Note that it will also match `http://abc.com/blahblah` and will fail to match `http://abc.com/./blah`. If this is a problem, you might want to consider using a URL parsing library instead.

Comment: thanks. I found this - http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/ should do what i need.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that would be ".*" -- the dot matches anything, and the asterisk means as many as you want.

So, in your example:

```
 http://abc[.]com/blah.*
```

You need the [.] in brackets so that it will match just the actual literal "dot".

Comment: It might be a good idea to include a [start of string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) too, to avoid accidentally matching `http://example.com/redirect?url=http://abc.com/blah`.